# How do I simplify(expand) this Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

Expression - `(A OR B OR C OR D) AND (!B AND !D)`

I know that with distributive property, it holds that `(a OR b) AND (c OR d) = (a AND c) OR (a AND d) OR (b AND c) or (b AND d)` but I'm not sure how it will work if the second group has an `AND`

Steps in the answer would help.

Comment: While boolean logic is often used in programs and programming, this seems more to be about the mathematical properties of boolean algebra. As such it should probably be posted on [the Math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
  (A OR B OR C OR D) AND (!B AND !D)
= (A OR B OR C OR D) AND !(B OR D)
= ((A OR C) OR (B OR D)) AND !(B OR D)
= ((A OR C) AND !(B OR D)) OR ((B OR D) AND !(B OR D))
= (A OR C) AND !(B OR D) OR false
= (A OR C) AND !(B OR D)
```

That seems like it's going to be minimal since each variable appears once and there are no apparent contradictions or tautologies.